# Можно ли собрать данные о среднем чеке через API Яндекс.Карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

У меня есть набор данных по ресторанам из яндекс карт. Мне необходимо добавить к ним значения среднего чека. В самих яндекс картах такие данные есть, а через API Поиска по организациям (https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/?from=mapsapi) эти данные не предоставляются.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить эти данные на основе адреса, названия, координат ресторана?

Answer (score 1):

Если в API эти данные не предоставляются, то можно сделать это примерно вот так.

tokio_city название, 109027798556 ID, ll координаты

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
import re
result = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/maps/org/tokio_city/109027798556/?ll=30.315564%2C59.933056').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

average_bill_elements = soup.select('.business-features-view__valued-value')
if average_bill_elements:
    average_bills = [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in average_bill_elements]
    for average_bill in average_bills:
        if re.match(r'\d+', average_bill):
            print(average_bill)
else:
    print("Не удалось найти информацию о среднем счёте.")
```

Однако прошу заметить, что этот подход запрещён со стороны сервисов Yandex, лучше обратиться в поддержку Yandex и обсудить с ними возможность реализации требующегося вам функционала.

Comment: Если ответ помог решить вашу проблему прошу отметить его как правильный. Всего доброго!